# Loop through each user in the list returned by the method

Tags: c#, list, loops, for-loop, foreach

My code works currently but I would like to make it so that it doesn't make the database call multiple times but it can get expensive if many `User IDs` are entered in the `request`. So, I started by concatenating the `list` of `users` into a string separated by commas which my `DataAccess` layer method allows so that it can return the `list` of `users` with their `start` and `end` time.

My data looks like this:

```
UserId     Time     EventType
Test1   xx-xx-xxxx   Start
Test1   xx-xx-xxxx   End
Test1   xx-xx-xxxx   Start
Test1   xx-xx-xxxx   End
Test2   xx-xx-xxxx   Start
Test2   xx-xx-xxxx   End
```

My problem is that... I can move the DataAccess Layer call outside the `foreach` loop and but how can I loop through each User from the returned `list` by my function? Currently, I am making the call individually for each `user`.

My code:

```
var userList = string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(request.Users, x => x.ToString()));
response.UserRecordList = new List<UserRecord>();

foreach (String userId in request.Users) // request.Users is a Array of UserId's 
{
    List<UserModel> result = // I am making my DataAccess Layer call here.
    UserRecord record = new UserRecord();
    record.UserId = userId;
    record.TimePeriodList = new List<TimePeriod>();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i += 2)
    {
        TimePeriod timeData = new TimePeriod();
        timeData.StartTime = result[i].TimeDate;
        timeData.EndTime = result[i + 1].TimeDate;
        record.TimePeriodList.Add(timeData);
        }
        response.UserRecordList.Add(record);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
response.UserRecordList = new List<UserRecord>();
var userList = string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(request.Users, x => x.ToString()));
List<UserModel> result = // EDIT - I am making my DataAccess Layer call here.

foreach (var resultList in result) // EDIT - iterate through the returned list
{
    UserRecord record = new UserRecord();
    record.UserId = userId;
    record.TimePeriodList = new List<TimePeriod>();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i += 2)
    {
        TimePeriod timeData = new TimePeriod();
        timeData.StartTime = result[i].TimeDate;
        timeData.EndTime = result[i + 1].TimeDate;
        record.TimePeriodList.Add(timeData);
        }
        response.UserRecordList.Add(record);
}
```

I am starting to iterate through the `result` list that is returned by my method. The issue is that I don't have that list organized by a User Id and ALL it's start and end. I have it so it has the User Id then it's start time... User Id then it's end time. So if my data displayed in the xml is being repeated how ever many times the user is in the list.

Comment: Pass the user ids in one go to DB using "IN" clause? Like `select * from table where userids in (1, 2, 3)` ?

Comment: I can't make database call changes. I have to organize the data in my webservice it self @nawfal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think I exactly get your problem, but I think you could use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to enumerate the collection per user. Like

```
var userList = string.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(request.Users, x => x.ToString()));
List<UserModel> result = // move it outside foreach and pass userList to make database call.

foreach (var resultList in result.GroupBy(x => x.UserId))
{
    var perUserResults = resultList.ToList();
    UserRecord record = new UserRecord();
    record.UserId = resultList.Key; //key is the user id field since we have grouped on UserId
    record.TimePeriodList = new List<TimePeriod>();
    for (int i = 0; i < perUserResults.Count; i += 2)
    {
        TimePeriod timeData = new TimePeriod();
        timeData.StartTime = perUserResults[i].TimeDate;
        timeData.EndTime = perUserResults[i + 1].TimeDate;
        record.TimePeriodList.Add(timeData);
    }

    response.UserRecordList.Add(record);
}
```

Comment: @user4756836 The inner loop is just like the foreach loop you have. It is not pretty clear how you want things. May be editing your question helps.

Comment: @user4756836 see my update. In case I am close to what u want I hope the idea is clear for you.

Comment: @nawfal that works! Good explanation as well! Thanks!

Comment: @user4756836 the key here is the inner loop. A `GroupBy` returns inner sequences grouped on particular keys (with `.Key` being a property itself on the inner sequence). So you just have to enumerate the inner sequence (in above code it is the `ToList()` part) to get items in a group and call `.Key` to get the grouping parameter itself. Understading LINQ makes things considerably easier.